# How to add authentication in static generated NuxtJS website

Tags: vue.js, axios, seo, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I built a website using NuxtJS, I used the SSR and `target: 'server'`, but now I need to optimize my website for SEO, and SMO, so for this I need to set the `target: 'static'`, because it's important to have server side rendered pages when sharing it in social media.

Problems
I'm using nuxtjs auth module for api authentication using Laravel Sanctum.
When I set the `target: 'static'`, it's proxy does not work, which means it's axios fetching links are not working.

So now how to make my website SEO, and SMO friendly?